# Redirect in .htaccess if condition is not true

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, magento

I'm trying to redirect my clients from:
`/media/pdf/pds/.../file.pdf` ***->*** 
`/media/pdf/pds/English/.../file.pdf`

<del>My current approach, witch fails:</del>

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/pdf/pds/English/(.*)$
RedirectMatch 301 ^/media/pdf/pds/(.*)$ /media/pdf/pds/English/$1
```

My current approach, witch also fails: ***<- (edited)***

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/pdf/pds/English/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/pdf/pds/(.*)$ media/pdf/pds/English/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

I have also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?!English)
RedirectMatch 301 ^/media/pdf/pds/(.*)$ /media/pdf/pds/English/$1
```

Above examples comes from different tutorials where I have tried to seek out the answer, but sens thees fails I'm now leaving my hope to the heroes of Stack Overflow.

**Make me proud!** `;^)`

---

### Edit - adding additional information

It's a Magento installation so the htaccess file is pretty large. But maybe something else is interrupting the condition in some way.
I have only edited the top and bottom of the file.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/pdf/(.*)$ /media/pdf/$1

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

#php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
#BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
#Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none

SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(?i:pdf)$" requested_pdf=pdf
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_pdf
```

### Edit again - adding even more additional information

It seems we have a htaccess file in media folder as well, it follows:

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### I also added a new htaccess file in media/pdf folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/pdf/pds/English/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/pdf/pds/(.*)$ media/pdf/pds/English/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .htaccess right under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/media` directory have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  ## enable rewrites  
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /media/

    # your redirect rule
    RewriteRule ^(pdf/pds)/((?!English/).*)$ $1/English/$2 [NC,L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- Delete your .htaccess under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/media/pdf/` directory.
- Clear your browser cache and restart the browser.
- Only after your verify above code working change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Comment: I just tried this, still no luck though. I also tried this approach with the RewriteCond snippet.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I believe you have magento installed in $DOCUMENT_ROOT. Please check my edited answer. Use above .htaccess as is in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/media` folder.

Comment: OMG! I was just going to ask a smal simple question in the beginning and it turn out to be a mayham. Thanks to all of you for your help though, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will NOT work -- `RewriteCond` directive is from one module (mod_rewrite) while `RedirectMatch` is from another (mod_alias).

Your only choice is to use mod_rewrite directives only:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/pdf/pds/English/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/pdf/pds/(.+)$ /media/pdf/pds/English/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Must be something else as I do not see this rule working at all -- it returns 404 instead of 301. Try putting full URL in RewriteRule target: e.g. `http://www.elgawelding.com/media/pdf/pds/English/$1`

Comment: Sorry m8, didn't work either. Could it have to do with the RewriteCond? Is there anyway for me to track what's going on?

Comment: Added some additional information in my question that may help

Comment: Of course it does. You have placed rewrite rules on top .. but what about the rest?? Where is `RewriteEngine On` line?? It's way on bottom. Considering that rules processed in top-to-bottom order, they will be ignored since rewrite engine is not active.

Comment: So -- check my rule -- you will see that statement present. Now .. instead of doing what you do (placing the rules whenever you want), do it properly (I mean -- you have structure in place, so follow it). Place this rule just **after** `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: I updated the question again .. and I also tried what you described. I just dont update the question for every try I make. I know I struggle with this, it's not my expertise.

Comment: OK. Inside that .htaccess in **media** folder -- place the same rule (2 lines) after RewriteEngine line, but edit RewriteRule pattern a bit -- remove `media/` (since you are already in that folder) and try full URL in target part: `RewriteRule ^pdf/pds/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/media/pdf/pds/English/$1 [NC,L,R=301]`. RewriteCond should remain the same. **ALSO**, try clearing browser cache or at least restarting it, as modern browsers do cache 301 redirects (or just try different url/pdf file)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `RedirectMatch` is able to follow a `RewriteCond`. Use `RerwiteRule` instead.

```
# Matches the pdf path
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} /media/pdf/pds
# But not English
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/pdf/pds/English
# Rewrite with a 301
RewriteRule ^media/pdf/pds/(.*)$ media/pdf/pds/English/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks m8, but not quite there yet. Here is a live example with the code you wrote (with the "English" sub-folder) witch works: http://www.elgawelding.com/media/pdf/pds/English/SMAW%20-%20(Stick)%20-%20MMA%20Stainless%20Steel/Cromarod%20316L.pdf
But here it is with out the "English" sub-folder witch doesn't work: http://www.elgawelding.com/media/pdf/pds/SMAW%20-%20(Stick)%20-%20MMA%20Stainless%20Steel/Cromarod%20316L.pdf

Comment: @ErikLandvall Notice that in my RewriteRule, I don't have a `/` before `media` as you have in your rule.  `RewriteRule ^/media....` should be `RewriteRule ^media...` since rewrite rules begin after the first /